# AppleScript throws an error when creating a folder

Tags: applescript

Okay, maybe I AM stupid, but why it's happening?
Here's my code

```
set openedFile to (choose file with prompt "Select a file to read:" of type {"PNG"})

tell application "Finder"
    set parentFolder to POSIX path of (parent of openedFile as text)
    set icFolder to make new folder at parentFolder with properties {name:"resized imgs"}
end tell
```

And when I'm trying to run it and select a file I get this:

> error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." Number -10000
>   What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it on my own:

```
set parentFolder to container of openedFile
set icnsFolder to (make new folder at parentFolder with properties {name:"resizedicns"}) as alias
set ic512_2x to duplicate openedFile to icnsFolder
```

Answer (score 2):

The parentFolder line is causing your problems. First, there is no such command as "parent". The Finder has the command "container" to get the parent folder. Also you are messing things up using "POSIX file" and "as text". The openedFile is already in the proper format for the Finder, so you don't need to coerce it into any other form.

As such just change the parentFolder line to this. Good luck.

```
set parentFolder to container of openedFile
```

Comment: I tried this before and once again got this:

error "Can’t make «class cfol» \"Development\" of «class cfol» \"Documents\" of «class cfol» \"michaelmullins\" of «class cfol» \"Users\" of «class sdsk» of application \"Finder\" into type list, record or text." number -1700 from «class cfol» "Development" of «class cfol» "Documents" of «class cfol» "michaelmullins" of «class cfol» "Users" of «class sdsk» to list, record or text